# Why is Xcode complaining when using Mac Catalyst? OSError -10670

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-catalyst, osstatus

I've made an app for iOS 14 for iPhone and iPad. When I try to build for macOS as well by checking on the magic Mac box (in Deployment Info, in target settings), it builds: but when I run the app, I get this:

> The operation couldn't be completed (OSError -10670.)\    Domain:
> NSOSStatusErrorDomain\    Code: -10670\    User Info: {
> "_LSFunction" = "_LSOpenStuffCallLocal";
> "_LSLine" = 3664;\ }

I'm running the latest version of macOS and Xcode beta, I've cleaned the project, I've Googled -- I can't even *find* this particular error number -- and that's exhausted my problem-solving skills.

This happens when I create a brand new app from scratch, so it's not just my current app.

Am I really the only unlucky person to have seen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Xcode Beta 6. If you can find the built .app in derived data or wherever, you can double-click that and it’ll run.